# I need help clearing a JOptionPane error message

Tags: java, joptionpane

I am working on the piece of code below. So far I have fixed a few of the previous errors that this code had but I am stuck on the JOptionPane error message that I keep getting when I run this piece. The error is posted below as well. I am wondering if this is happening due to a typo that I'm missing or if it's something else as I am fairly new to using JOptionPane. Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions!

**Code:**

```
  public static void main(String args[])
   {
      char userCode;
      String entry, message;
      boolean found = false; 
      char[] okayCodes = {'A','C','T','H'}; 
      StringBuffer prompt = new 
            StringBuffer("Enter shipping code for this delivery\nValid codes are: ");
        for(int x = 0; x < okayCodes.length; ++x) 
        {
            prompt.append(okayCodes[x]);
            if(x != (okayCodes.length))
               prompt.append(", ");     
        }
      entry = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
          prompt); 
      userCode = entry.charAt(0); 
        for(int i = 0; i < okayCodes.length; ++i) 
        {
           if(userCode == okayCodes[i]) 
           {
              found = true; 
           }
        }
        if(found)
           message = "Good code";
        else
           message = "Sorry code not found";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
   }
}
```

**Error Message**

cannot find symbol entry = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,           prompt);

cannot find symbol JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);

symbol: variable JOptionPane

Comment: Code compiles fine for me. Do you have the proper import statement for the Swing components? Read the JOptionPane API to see what package you need to import. This is basic Java 101. Or, read the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for example you can download and test. They will have the proper import statements. If you need more help then post the code you are compiling showing that you have included the Swing import statements.

Comment: I think so. I have tried both import java.util.*; and import javax.swing.*; I tried using each one separately and then both together but it throws more error codes when I change it.  I will read the Swing tutorial and see if I can find what I need. Thanks again!

Comment: Using both should work. At least is does for me. Update your question with the exact code and imports.